# What is the Laspy error when reading laz files?

Tags: error-handling, laspy

```
import laspy 
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

las = laspy.read("file.laz")
```

When I use this code, I get the error: *laspy.errors.LaspyException: No LazBackend selected, cannot decompress data*

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 10):

The laspy website explains how to enable filehandling of .laz files.

https://laspy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#

You have to install one of the two given .laz backends.
On the top of the page are installation examples.

With unix/macOS this worked for me:

```
python3 -m pip install "laspy[lazrs,laszip]"
```

Make sure to reload your python environment after the installation.

Comment: I just want to add that your command didn't work for me on MacOS, but the following did: `pip install laspy` followed by `conda install -c conda-forge lazrs-python`

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and unfortunately, while working in colab, installing the `laspy` tool and the dependancies for .laz files using `!pip install laspy[lazrs,laszip]` did not help in reading the .laz file. Luckily, Qgis has the tool to convert from .las to .laz found in the Processing Toolbox > Point Cloud Conversion > Convert format. It also has the option of batch processing as well.